# Proxied Rails app relative_url_root not prefixing url helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reverse-proxy

So I have Nginx proxying a rails app with the following config

```
location ^~ /admin {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://admin/;
}
```

which has the affect of re-writing all requests to http://localhost/admin/XXX/YYY/ZZZ => http://admin/XXX/YYY/ZZZ

so next I ran into the issue of assets urls not pointing at the proxied app, so `config.relative_url_root = '/admin'` did the trick

Next problem is every link generated by link_to returns a link based at `/` not `/admin` which I would believe `config.relative_url_root` would change... Now I am sort of correct, If i go to `rails console` then `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` then call say `root_path` or `management_path`, I receive `/admin` and `/admin/management`. Perfect!

Now this is where I get rather confused. All the routes generated in my views disregard the prefix set by `config.relative_url_root`...
Why is this configuration option working in the console environment but not in the view environment?

config.relative_url_root is located in my application.rb

`Rails 5.1.5`

Answer (score 1):

This resolution is not quite what I was hoping for but in the meantime it works.

/config.ru

```
map ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT'] || "/" do
  run Rails.application
end
```

/nginx.conf

```
location ^~ /admin {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://HC_admin/admin;
}
```

All that changed is that the app itself now thinks it is running at `/admin` or whatever you set `RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT` to. This in my mind defeats the purpose of parts of your app being separated as you still need to configure where its mounted.

Found some instructions in a gist, [here](https://gist.github.com/ebeigarts/5450422)